# R's apply functions family

Tags: r

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [R Grouping functions: sapply vs. lapply vs. apply. vs. tapply vs. by vs. aggregate vs.](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3505701/r-grouping-functions-sapply-vs-lapply-vs-apply-vs-tapply-vs-by-vs-aggregat)

R's `apply` functions family is very handy. Almost everyday I come across new member of `apply` functions family. Today I came to know `eapply` through this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7410561/how-to-iterate-through-items-in-an-r-environment). I'd like to make a list of available `apply` functions family. I'd appreciate if you come up with some  `apply` functions family members with their description and possible example. Thanks in advance.

Comment: I wrote something like what you describe for many of the base apply family of functions [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3505701/r-grouping-functions-sapply-vs-lapply-vs-apply-vs-tapply-vs-by-vs-aggregat/7141669#7141669).

Comment: @ Joran: Nice answer and good collection. Thanks for pointing out.

Comment: @joran. Nice list. +10. Will probably recommend it in the future. You might consider expanding the `sapply` entry since you can expect matrices or arrays when multiple grouping factors are used.